# Tag a branch in TortoiseSVN - including its externals

Tags: tortoisesvn

Version 1.0 of my site is on the live server. Now I've made changes to the local repository, and I want to upload 1.1. Some of the changes we made in svn:external directories. When I tag the trunk and do a diff, it doesn't check any of its externals. This is apparently a known issue.

Is there anything I can do to make tortoise include the external repositories when tagging?

Comment: What is the meaning of "check" in "it doesn't check any of its externals"? Show us the hierarchy of your repository, and how externals are included. Also, do you reference externals with HEAD or with their revision numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in TortoiseSVN 1.7 the branch/tag dialog shows you all your externals and offers you to fix them to the current revision.
See the [release notes](http://tortoisesvn.net/tsvn_1.7_releasenotes.html#branchtag).

Answer (score 0):

Note: tagging with externals without PEF-revision is bad idea - you didn't fix externals, related to tag

Re-read docs about externals - changes in linked data appear only on export/new checkout, base repo doesn't have nothing physically in it